# Sending json data via POST to a Java API hosted by tomcat7, endpoint requiring MultivaluedMap, something is adding "= []" to my json object

Tags: java, json, post, tomcat7

First, here is the endpoint I am trying to access:

```
@POST
@Path("/endpoint")
@Produces("text/plain")
public Response authentication(MultivaluedMap<String, String> formParams) { 
    System.out.println(formParams.toString());
    String my = formParams.getFirst("my");
    // rest of the code...
}
```

Initially I was using @FormParam("jsonData") to get my json object. But then I would have to send my data like this:

```
jsonData={"my": "json data"}
```

I wanted to get rid of the 'jsonData=' at the beginning, and found that you can use MultivaluedMap to send only this:

```
{"my": "json data"}
```

But, when I try to test this with this **curl** request:

```
curl --data '{"my": "json data"}' https://mywebsite.com/my/endpoint -v -H "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

The server receives this:

```
{{"my": "json data"} = []}
```

And it is preventing me to do this:

```
String my = formParams.getFirst("my");
```

Since it thinks that the entire {"my": "json data"} is the key, binding to a null value.

I want to do something clean, my main objective is to send json via POST like this:

```
{"my": "json data"}
```

But it is sending funny data instead, and there is **no** topic on this particular issue. Can somebody help me send my json data like I want to?

Thanks for your help, don't hesitate to ask for more details!